# How to insert value in textarea in Flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have a form:

`class simple_order(Form):
    order_info = TextAreaField()`
,in the template i am added: 
`{{form.order_info(cols=60, rows=20)}}`

How to add text into render textarea, like value in the `input` tag?

Comment: There is a attribute named placeholder of textarea.

Comment: placeholder - displays the text inside a form field that disappears when it has focus

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do it.

i. When creating a model you can do like below:

```
order_info = TextAreaField(default='This is default text')
```

ii. Before rendering the form, you can add the content:

```
form = simple_order()
form.order_info.data = 'This is default text'
```

Hope it helps.